# Invalid object name 'view3' - How can I access a view in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

```
create view view3 as
(
    select distinct 
        tblDivingClub.number as divingClub,
        (select count(*) 
         from tblAuthorized 
         WHERE tblAuthorized.club_number = tblDivingClub.number 
           and tblAuthorized.authorization_date <= DATEADD(month,-1, GETDATE())) as levels, 
        (select count(*) 
         from tblDiving 
         WHERE tblDiving.diving_club=tblDivingClub.number 
           and tblDiving.date_of_diving <= DATEADD(month,-1, GETDATE())) as divings
    from 
       tblDiving, tblDivingClub, tblAuthorized
)
go

create view view2 as
(
    select 
       divingClub
    from 
       view3
)
go
```

When I'm trying to create `view2` based on `view3`, SQL Server doesn't recognize `view3`. I'm getting this error:

> Invalid object name 'view3'

How can I access `view3`?

Ty

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a similar scenario in one of my databases and like this it should work (brackets gave me error's on SQL Server 2008 R2 otherwise it seems fine)

```
CREATE VIEW view3
AS
        SELECT DISTINCT tblDivingClub.number AS divingClub
            ,(
                SELECT count(*)
                FROM tblAuthorized
                WHERE tblAuthorized.club_number = tblDivingClub.number
                    AND tblAuthorized.authorization_date <= DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE())
                ) AS levels
            ,(
                SELECT count(*)
                FROM tblDiving
                WHERE tblDiving.diving_club = tblDivingClub.number
                    AND tblDiving.date_of_diving <= DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE())
                ) AS divings
        FROM tblDiving
            ,tblDivingClub
            ,tblAuthorized

GO

CREATE VIEW view2
AS
    SELECT divingClub
    FROM view3
GO 

SELECT * FROM VIEW2
```